# How to bring a feature marker to the front in openlayers?

Tags: openlayers

I drew several featrues(OpenLayers.Feature.Vector) on the layer,rendering as follows:

[image]

The question is how to bring the feature marker "H" to the front when it is clicked.

I used 'drawFeature()' method to redraw it ,but it remained the way it was.

Does anyone know why? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about if you use "hover" to bring that to the front? like this:

```
http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/highlight-feature.html
```

if you draw two overlapping polygons with:

```
http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/select-feature.html
```

you will see that hover would work for you.

Comment: you need to be more specific and add details to your comments such as error messages, code, etc, just "sorry, it does not work" won't add anything to solve your issue.

Comment: OK.In fact,'eraseFeature()' method should be called before 'drawFeature()'.Anyway, thank you!